# How to limit a size of data stored into mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have multi tenant application where each tenant can store some data into MongoDB. Now I want to apply a capping on each tenant data stored into MongoDB based on subscription plan.

My problem is how to calculate each document size stored into MongoDB by each customer?

One option is to have separate database for each tenant have size limit on that db. But maintenance point of view this seems tidious. Is there any other option where I can share db among tenants and calculate each tenant record size to keep track of storage?

Comment: I think that you are doing it wrong. Stop your current approach of thinking from the side of DB, there can be many changes in newer versions. But rather why don't you approach the formula to count the storage needed from the application? You wrote that you have the app, so go ahead and measure/analyze it from app perspective and save yourself many headaches later on. Also I would not block it I/O wise (there are terms like soft and hard quota, etc.) but place blocks from the app, once you have calculations, you can count with it.

Comment: mongodb is quite good at handling multiple databases. Having 1 db per client can significantly simplify application logic, security, and maintenance cost in most scenarios.

Comment: @AlexBlex And it makes things significantly harder that involve more than one database like overall statistics, cleanup jobs, etc., and it makes joins using `$lookup` aggregations impossible.

Comment: @str fair enough. I imagine there must be some cases where it doesn't work, but cross-tenant `$lookup` over user-generated data sounds a bit odd.

Comment: @AlexBlex Cross-tenant is probably very rare, but tenant-specific DB to general, shared user DB is not.